# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

Tags: io, f#

I have a file `Roman_Numbers.txt`, and i put it next to my `*.fsx`file in the folder of project. Then I tried to read this file using the following function in the `fsx` file:

```
    open System.IO
    let readNumbersFromFile(path:string)=
       let lines = File.ReadLines(path)
       let ListOfNumbers = List.ofSeq(lines);
       checkConvert  ListOfNumbers

    readNumbersFromFile(@"Roman_Numbers.txt")
```

But i face with this erorr:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Salman\AppData\Local\Temp\Roman_Numbers.txt'.
> File name: 'C:\Users\Salman\AppData\Local\Temp\Roman_Numbers.txt'
```

The question is: Why it should look for `C:\Users\Salman\AppData\Local\Temp\Roman_Numbers.txt'` this address, meanwhile 
my project is not here and more over i clearly mention  `Roman_Numbers.txt` as a source of file?

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should copy the file into your package folder and specify the complete path into your code. Try that and see the result

Answer (score 1):

Use **SOURCE_DIRECTORY**

```
readNumbersFromFile( __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ +  @"/Roman_Numbers.txt")
```

Comment: Could u expand your answer for write too?

Comment: What do you mean with "expanding for write" ?

Comment: Sorry, i found out my mistake

Comment: Maybe use `System.IO.Path.Combine`: `readNumbersFromFile (Path.Combine (__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__, "Roman_Numbers.txt"))`.